# Convert Java String returned from JDBC to Json object

Tags: java, json

great Genius people, I need help in solving a java problem related to java. In a program I am making a JDBC call and the function returns a string similar to this:

```
[[{PROD_CD=42, SHORT_DESC=WATERFALL EDGE}, {PROD_CD=31, SHORT_DESC=N/A}, {PROD_CD=51, SHORT_DESC=OGEE EDGE}]]
```

I need to get rid of curly braces, commas, and save it as a json object.

```
[
  {
    "PROD_CD": " 42",
    "SHORT_DESC": "WATERFALL EDGE",
  },
  {
    "PROD_CD": "31",
    "SHORT_DESC": "N/A",
  },
  {
    "PROD_CD": "51",
    "SHORT_DESC": "OGEE EDGE",
  }
]
```

I highly appreciate your help

Here is What I tried so far:

```
@Override
    public Map<String, String> getEdgeCd() {


        Map<String, String> EdgeCd = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map<String,Object> temp = new HashMap<String,Object>();


        try {


            SimpleJdbcCall fgetEdgeCd = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                    .withSchemaName("logprd")
                    .withCatalogName("edge_api_pkg")
                    .withFunctionName("DDGetEdgeCd");


            temp = fgetEdgeCd.execute();
            System.out.println("temp " + temp + "  \n\n\n\n\n\n");
            System.out.println("temp.values() " + temp.values() + " lines \n\n\n\n\n\n");

            String keyList =  temp.values().toString();
```

**//THIS IS RETURNED AS THE FOLLOWING STRING:**

```
String keyList =  "[[{PROD_CD=42, SHORT_DESC=WATERFALL EDGE}, {PROD_CD=31, SHORT_DESC=N/A}, {PROD_CD=51, SHORT_DESC=OGEE EDGE}]]"; 
String[] currentLine;

currentLine = keyList.substring(3, keyList.length() -3).split("[}]|[{]");
String currenLineString = Arrays.toString(currentLine);

String newCurrentLineString = currenLineString.substring(1, keyList.length()-1).replaceAll("," , "").replaceAll(" EDGE" , "-Edge").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
//System.out.println("newCurrentLineString:>"+ newCurrentLineString + "\n\n");
String[] testLine;
testLine = newCurrentLineString.split(" ");


ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>();
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map=new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
Collection<String> keyValue = null;
    for(int i=0; i< testLine.length; i++) {
     String[] temp = testLine[i].toString().split("=");
    keyValue.addAll(Arrays.asList(temp));
    System.out.println( "keyValue"+i + ":>"+ keyValue.toString() + "\n\n");

    for (int j=0; j < keyValue.size(); j+=2) {
     map.put(temp[j].toString(), temp[j+1].toString());
     //map.put(keyValue[i].toString(), keyValue[i+1].toString());
     //System.out.println( "mapmain:>"+ map.toString() + "\n\n");
     data.add(map);
     System.out.println(map.toString());
     System.out.println(data.toString());

    }//end for j
   }end for i
      } catch (Exception e) {

            logger.error("Error trying JDBC");
    }

        return EdgeCd;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing some code?

Comment: Did you write that method or is that string provided by the database? If so, which database are you using?

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara I did try some

Comment: @Thomas This returned by JDBC, database from SQL side.

Comment: What Abubakkar meant was: _what_ did you try (tell/show us)? So you're using an SQL database? That doesn't help much. Please add more information (e.g. database and version, query you're using etc.) in order to enable us to help.

Comment: @Thomas I am really non a java person. I get confused between List, Map, Hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer,
but not, necessarily the answer you want.

1. Look at the data that is returned from the database.  Notice that it has an obvious pattern.
2. There are three basic objects in the data that is returned from the database; an array, a container object, a key-value pair.  The array is an array of container objects.  The container object contains one or more key-value pairs.  The key-value pair is composed of two String values.
3. Create a parser that parses the data which is returned from the database.  I recommend against attempting to "fix" it with a regular expression, just parse it with code.
4. Using the three objects mentioned above, create an object representation of the data using the parser (also mentioned above).
5. Output the objects as json.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick function in C# that is easily portable to JAVA (sorry I don't have a JAVA compiler on my phone). The main issues will be in assuming the spaces and escaping characters if the curly brackets or commas appear in the record data.

```
        string data = "[[{PROD_CD=42, SHORT_DESC=WATERFALL EDGE}, {PROD_CD=31, SHORT_DESC=N/A}, {PROD_CD=51, SHORT_DESC=OGEE EDGE}]]";

        char[] chars = data.ToCharArray();
        StringBuilder currentRecord = null;
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder("[");

        bool isInCurly = false;// Loop state 
        for (int i=0;i<chars.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (chars[i] == '{')
            {
                isInCurly = true;
                currentRecord = new StringBuilder("{");
            }
            else if (chars[i] == '}')
            {
                currentRecord.Append("}");
                isInCurly = false;

                // Major assumptions made here about the structure that will need to be verified such as ", " between record values, etc...
                string cleanRecord = currentRecord.ToString().Replace("{", "{\"")
                                                             .Replace("=", "\":\"")
                                                             .Replace(", ", "\", \"")
                                                             .Replace("}", "\"}");
                json.AppendLine(cleanRecord + ", ");
            }
            else if(isInCurly)
            {
                currentRecord.Append(chars[i]);
            }
        }            
        json.Append("]");
        string finalJson = json.ToString();
```

Results 
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Joseph Rosson

Comment: If it solved your problem, please remember to accept the answer.